# Alert Dialog on onTap on ListTile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I create a AlertDialog by clicking/tapping on ListTile.
Currently I'm doing this and nothing happens when it's clicked.

```
body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Theme'),
            onTap: (){
              AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Hi'),
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
```

PS: I'm a noob, please go easy on me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are very close, you created the dialog, just need to show it:

```
body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Theme'),
            onTap: () {
              AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Hi'),
              );
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return alert;
                },
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `ListTile` with this.

```
ListTile(
  title: Text('Theme'),
  onTap: () {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Alert Dialog Example'),
            content: Text('Alert Dialog Body Goes Here  ..'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  child: Text('OK')),
            ],
          );
        });
  },
)
```

I have also added some properties to use the `AlertDialog()`, like **title**, **content** and **actions**