# How to create alert dialog on onTap on ListTile and select option to replace listTile value

Tags: flutter, dialog, flutter-dialog

> Greetings everyone I'm new to flutter I need help implementing the simple feature of the Dialog.

- I have a listTile consisting of members with different roles (Tressure, Secretary, Chair Person, and Ordinary Member)
- Firstly I want to create an Alert dialog so that when I click on each listTile the dialog should pop up with the title "Change Member role" and below it should be the selectable options to set the selected option to the listTile
- I need help creating the Alert dialog with these options and how to go about setting the text for the selected option to ListTile.
- below is the link where I found the design, now I need the source code to implement the code

[Click here for understanding the design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61179035/alert-dialog-on-ontap-on-listtile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would make a class to represent a member `Member` (with fields like `id`, `name`, `role`, whatever else you need).

Then have a Provider for managing the members data. It will contain list of members like `List<Member>` and methods to make changes for this list. For example: for changing member's role it will contain `changeMemberRole(int memberID)` method, that will modify data in that list and call `notifyListeners();` in the end.

After that on the screen that need to show list of members I would get an instance of this provider, build all list tiles using it's data, and it will automatically rebuild the list once data changes.

Links that should help:

[Simple state management (for understanding Providers)](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

[Using modal bottom sheet (for dialog)](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/modal-bottom-sheet-in-flutter-dae05debbed2), but you can [use AlertDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) as well